# Lookup all Navision Objects

Tags: navision, cal, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I want to make a field to lookup all  NAvision objects or specific objects(e.g all codeunits or Pages etc). but i dont know how to achieve this.

Comment: Explain best your question,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a field in the desired table
go to the properties of the field and add AllObjWithCaption."Object ID" to the TableRelation.

Comment: Example TableRelation showing tables "Gen. Journal Line" or "Item Journal Line": 
AllObjWithCaption."Object ID" WHERE (Object Type=CONST(TableData),Object ID=FILTER(81|83))

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to hidden system table called something like `AllObjWithCaptions`. You can find it at the very bottom of the table list if you open lookup in table relation property of a field.

Comment: Thanks for ur help